# How to add Modal in Bootstrap Sub Theme

Tags: theming

I am trying to make a sub theme based on Bootstrap 3 Drupal theme.

I want to add a modal markup in every page. I can see in the base Bootstrap theme template files, there is a file called modal.tpl.php with corresponding HTML markup but I do not know how to include it into my page. Anyone can help?

Comment: Do you want every page to open in a modal? Or just some modal content on every page?

Comment: To be exactly, I want the modal to be showed on all the node except for front page

Answer (score 1):

First refer to the bootstrap documentation on modals http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ to construct a working modal with the content you want. Use bootply or whatever to get it working the way you want.

You then have two options that come to mind: You could just create a standard block using the Drupal UI, place the markup in the body of the block, and configure the block to "display on every page except" ... `<front>`. Then assign the block to a region.

Alternatively, you can override tpl files in your subtheme and place the modal markup in those. You do this by placing a copy of the Bootstrap theme's `page.tpl.php` in your subtheme. First create a copy of it called `page--front.tpl.php` then add your modal markup to `page.tpl.php`.